# How to run android app in latest version of react-native( 0.49)

Tags: react-native

In the latest version of reatc-native i.e. 0.49, there is only one class index.js
it is working fine for ios, but in android it always gives an error i.e  "unexpected token .: parse error (index.android.bundle:1)"

In pervious version of react-native(0.47),two separate file were generated i.e. index.ios.js and index.android.js. so android easily find index.android.bundle, that was the reason of app working fine in Android, but now in the latest version of react-native(0.49)android couldn't find index.android.bundle.

can any one please tell me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **gradlew clean** and rebuild your all using react-native run-androi.

In ubuntu or mac
From your project root directory

```
cd android 
./gradlew clean
```

In windows

```
cd android
gralew.bat clean
```

Comment: I was doing the same, but not working, same error is raised again.

Comment: Then you can  create index.android.js and index.ios.js
And try to build the app.